# This makefile only creates .o files

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to practice using Makefiles for a very simple program. The program files are:

```
main.cpp
other.cpp
other.h
```

I want the final executable to be Prog.

What happens when I run this is I get a main.o and other.o but no Prog.

What am I missing here?

```
## file Makefile

CXXOBJECTS= %.o
CXX= g++ 
CXXSOURCES= main.cpp other.cpp
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -O2


Prog : main.o other.o


main.o : main.cpp 
other.o : other.cpp other.h




## eof Makefile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You have the following:

```
Prog: main.o other.o ## these are your dependencies
    g++ main.o other.o -o Prog
```

This should give you an executable called `Prog`. Though actually, a better makefile would be this:

```
CXXOBJECTS= %.o
CXX= g++ 
CXXSOURCES= main.cpp other.cpp
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -O2

Prog: main.o other.o ## these are your dependencies
    CXX main.o other.o -o Prog

main.o : main.cpp
    CXX CXXFLAGS -c main.cpp

other.o : other.cpp
    CXX CXXFLAGS -c other.cpp
```

Actually, you can make it even better, but I don't remember the syntactic sugar of makefiles off the top of my head (IDE's :P)

Comment: Awesome, just that one line :P

Comment: I apparently need 15 rep to vote up... I'll 'check' in 4 minutes :)

Comment: @IBit That's alright, as long as your MF is working :)

Comment: I think your variable references need to look more like `$(THIS)`... Otherwise, they're a wee bit broken...

Comment: @twalberg you're right. Haven't used makefiles in a while... maybe I shouldn't have answered this question